# Rmagik image.orientation type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave, rmagick

I'm trying to get the exif data from the image.
I tried to puts

```
1.
puts img.orientation
#TopLeftOrientation

2.
puts img.orientation
#UndefinedOrientation
```

How I actually can compare the value.

if i puts img.orientation.inspect
I get some values

```
TopLeftOrientation=1
UndefinedOrientation=0
```

I want to get the value of 1 to 0 ,to perform my logic, is there a way?

Besides, I found out some resource
http://blog.choonkeat.com/weblog/2007/10/lesson-1-after-.html
when:

```
img["EXIF:Orientation"] == "6"
```

it will rotate!(90)

but in my case,i got image that is "6", but it don't need to be rotate. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The numbers you are seeing relate to the EXIF orientation spec:
http://sylvana.net/jpegcrop/exif_orientation.html

Those map directly to these:
http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/constants.html#OrientationType

You could simply img.orientation.to_i to get the integer value or use a case statement to derive it based on the constants in the links above.

Sometimes EXIF data is just plain wrong. So take that with a grain of salt too, that the EXIF data for some images might be flawed.

Lastly, I'm not sure if it's of use to you, but there is an img.auto_orient! which will force the image to the proper orientation for you automatically based on the EXIF data.

Comment: I recommend not using the "bang" (`!`) with `auto_orient`. People, like myself, assume that it will orient the image and save it, which it does not. The image still needs to be saved after `auto_orient` is called.